# Javascript not assign to variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm writing a basic user creation system in Node.js and I want to find out what the results of the createUser function are. The code itself works fine, with new users being posted, and already existing users being stopped. I would like to show this to the end user, so I setup a variable to return a numeric value representing what the outcome was.

The problem is, the value is never assigned to. The final console log always reads undefined, even though my other log statements appear. I feel like this is more of a JavaScript syntax question, but I am stumped.

```
User.prototype.createUser = function () {
    console.log('Begin createUser...');
    var email = this.email;
    var wasUserCreated;  <------- variable to assign
    pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function (err, client) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message, err.stack);
            wasUserCreated = 0; <------assigning to variable?
        }
        else {
            var query = client.query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=$1', [email], 
            function (err, results) {
                if (results.rows.length > 0) {
                    console.log('That email address has already been registered!');
                    wasUserCreated = 1; <------assigning to variable?

                }
                else {
                    console.log('Email address not found, inserting new account');
                    insertNewUser();
                    wasUserCreated = 2; <------assigning to variable?

                }
            });
        }
    });
    console.log("wasUserCreated: " + wasUserCreated); <------always reads 'undefined'

    return wasUserCreated;
};
```

Comment: **A**synchronous. Unrelated, but I'd shy away from using numeric values for what's essentially a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to your query being asynchronous - what your createUser method should do is take a callback as an argument, and invoke cb(err, wasUserCreated, user) or something inside the callback to your query.

Your console.log is always undef because it fires synchronously

[some basics in mixu's node book](http://book.mixu.net/node/ch2.html)

Answer (score 0):

the 2nd argument of *pg.connect* is a callback function, which runs asynchronously... so the function returns before the *wasUserCreated* is modified